# How do I add a target line for each bar in a bar chart with Plotly?

Tags: plotly, bar-chart, plotly.js

I am using the Plotly Panel plugin for Grafana and would like to plot a the Setpoint and Actual values for several variables.

I am able to generate a graph as below:

[image: grouped bar chart]

using the following script:

```js
var trace0 = {
    x: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    y: [100, 40, 130],
    type: 'bar',
    name: 'Setpoint'
    };
var trace1 = {
    x: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    y: [87, 46, 112],
    type: 'bar',
    name: 'Actual'
};

return {data:[trace0, trace1],layout:{title:'Control'}};
```

This works. However, I think that having the "Setpoint" as a line over each "Actual" bar would be more compact while also making the graph more intuitive.
Here is the Mockup of the chart I did with Google Sheets + Paint:
[image: Mockup of desired chart]

I also had a look at the bullet chart to see if I could use it for this purpose but couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that displaying *only* the topmost portion of the Setpoint bar is difficult to do. I think your best choice to get the desired display is to use `Shapes` which you can read about [here](https://plotly.com/javascript/shapes/), and draw the Setpoint bar using horizontal lines based on the x- and y-coordinates of the chart.

Each line is defined by the parameters `x0, y0, x1, y1` where `(x0, y0)` is the starting coordinate of the line and `(x1, y1)` is the ending coordinate .

For a bar chart with a categorical x-axis, the x-coordinates are in fact directly mapped to 0, 1, 2.... this means that we can use a counter `i` to loop through the array of values for the Setpoint bars, and make line extend from `x0 = i - width / 2` to `x0 = i + width / 2`, and set both y0 and y1 to be the y value of the Setpoint bar. The default bars have a width of 0.8, so you can make the width of the lines slightly longer (I chose 0.9) to get as close to your output as possible.

I defined arrays to hold your bar categories, setpoint bar values, and setpoint bar width (which we can think of as the length of the line shape we are using). Hopefully this means my solution is more generalizable.

```
categories = ['A', 'B', 'C']
setPointValues = [100, 40, 130]
setPointWidth = 0.9

var trace1 = {
    x: categories,
    y: [87, 46, 112],
    type: 'bar',
    marker: {
      color: 'orange'
    },
    name: 'Actual'
};
setPointLines = []
for (i=0; i<categories.length; i++){
  setPointLines.push(
    {
      type: 'line',
            // x-reference is assigned to the x-values
            xref: 'x',
            // y-reference is assigned to the plot paper [0,1]
            yref: 'y',
            x0: i-setPointWidth/2,
            y0: setPointValues[i],
            x1: i+setPointWidth/2,
            y1: setPointValues[i],
            line: {
                color:'blue',
                width: 2
            }
    }
  )
}

var layout = {
  title: 'Control',
  shapes: setPointLines
};

var data = [trace1];

return {data:[trace1],layout:{title:'Control'}};
```

[image]